# Precise definition of HL7(v2) field RXE-25?

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

Can anyone explain what the field of RXE-25 in HL-7v2 means?  The description is "Give strength".  I have read the official explanation, but I feel this is ambiguous.  I am not sure whether this field should contain a)the strength of a single tablet/dose form vs b)the total strength to administer.

For example, hydroxychloroquine [HCQ] is a lupus medication that comes in 200 mg tablets.  Lupus patients are frequently started off on 400 mg of this per day (ie 2 tablets).

Let's say RXE-3 ("Give Amount - Minimum") is "**2**", and RXE-5 ("Give Units") is "**tablet**".  And let's assume there are multiple tablet strengths, so we don't know what dose that is.  Would one put the per-tablet dose in RXE-25 (ie "**200**" mg), or instead put the entire dose (2 tablets="**400**" mg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer hidden in another part of the HL7 documentation, specifically under the RXO segment (RXO-18 Requested Give Strength).  Per that documentation, this applies to various RX_ segments.

The example given:

> One way would be: "Ampicillin 250 mg capsules, 2 capsules four times a
>   day." In this case the give amount would be 2, the give units would be
>   capsules, the strength would be 250 and the strength units would
>   milligrams.

So it seems the GIVE STRENGTH AMOUNT (if present, and no GIVE DRUG STRENGTH VOLUME is specified) is multiplied by the GIVE AMOUNT to come up with the total dose.  So I believe the answer to the example in the question would be a) 200 mg.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of all the 'Give' fields is they represent the amount given per dose. So to answer your questions:

b)the total strength to administer

AND

put the entire dose (2 tablets="400" mg)

Comment: Actually, I think it is the other one.  See my answer.